# Iterating over a generic ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of a generic type as shown below:

```
List<abcparsepojo> xyzintrunsiveObjects = (List<abcparsepojo>)abcparseGetter.getObjects(file);
```

How can I iterate over this `ArrayList` as I want to print its contents on the console? I have crosschecked (while debugging and inspecting) that it had got the contents. Can I use the advance `for` loop for this?

Comment: why not? you can try it. it wont bite you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Best way to iterate through an Collection (here ArrayList)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228687/java-best-way-to-iterate-through-an-collection-here-arraylist)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
List<abcparsepojo> xyzintrunsiveObjects = (List<abcparsepojo>)abcparseGetter.getObjects(file);
for(abcparsepojo pojo: xyzintrunsiveObjects) {
    //do something with pojo
    System.out.println(pojo.getSomeProperty())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do that :

1.Enhanced for loop

```
    List<abcparsepojo> xyzintrunsiveObjectsList = 
                             (List<abcparsepojo>)abcparseGetter.getObjects(file);
    for(abcparsepojo element: xyzintrunsiveObjectsList) {
       //use element here
    }
```

**AND**

2.Using `Iterator`. This is useful if you want to remove elements from `List`.

```
List<abcparsepojo> xyzintrunsiveObjectsList = 
                             (List<abcparsepojo>)abcparseGetter.getObjects(file);
Iterator<abcparsepojo> pojoIterator = xyzintrunsiveObjectsList .iterator();
while(pojoIterator .hasNext()){
   abcparsepojo element = (abcparsepojo)pojoIterator.next();
   //use element here
}
```