# Using iterator to manipulate complicated objects in ArrayList?

Tags: java, iterator

I successfully sort students by id using comparator and displayed using for loop, I hope to know how can I make it happen with iterator, well I tried but only address in console and have no idea of how to print info from Student class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student stu1 = new Student("Lucy",1000,99);
    Student stu2 = new Student("Jack",1001,22);
    Student stu3 = new Student("Peter",1002,53);

    ArrayList<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();
    student.add(stu1);
    student.add(stu2);
    student.add(stu3);

    Collections.sort(student,new StuCOmp("id"));
    for (int i=0; i<student.size(); i++) {
        Student stu = student.get(i);
        System.out.println(stu.getName() + " "+stu.getId()+ " "+stu.getGrade());    
    }

    Iterator<Student> it = student.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){

        //what do I write here
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterator doesn't have many methods. Have you checked uits javadoc? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: You basically do the same thing as you would do with a normal `for` loop. Assign `it.next()` to temp variable, do whatever, repeat.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228687/java-best-way-to-iterate-through-an-collection-here-arraylist

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate it like this in for loop -

```
       for (Iterator<Student> iterator = student.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Student stu = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(stu.getName() + " "+stu.getId()+ " "+stu.getGrade());
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a raw Iterator. Use an `Iterator<Student>`

Comment: @Suresh:Thanks, once `Iterator<Student>` is used, no need to caste.

Comment: @JavaLearner Yes. Now it seems ok. +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator itr=student.iterator();  
  while(itr.hasNext()){  
    Student stu=(Student)itr.next();  
    System.out.println(stu.getName() + " "+stu.getId()+ " "+stu.getGrade());
```

Comment: the sys out prints the object means as hash code of object student will be printed. No use of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator<Student> it = student.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        // You should write here:   
        Student stu = it.next();
        System.out.println(stu.getName() + " "+stu.getId()+ " "+stu.getGrade());
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using an iterator and use an enhanced for loop.

```
for (Student st : student)
    System.out.println(st.getName() + " "+st.getId()+ " "+st.getGrade());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
Iterator<Student> it = student.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  Student student=it.next();// you can get the students one by one  
  // Now you can get the each student info
  //student.any attribute
}
```

This way is very similar to `for-each` but `iterator` is faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator itr=student.iterator();  
  while(itr.hasNext()){  
    Student stu=(Student)itr.next();  
    System.out.println("whatever you want to print");
```