# Java, How Iterate through Collection<? extends E>?

Tags: java, collections, iteration, abstract-data-type

so I was given an interface where one method I need to implement gives me a Collection and wants me to "addAll" the data in the collection to my object. I'm still not sure what exactly a collection is. Is it an array list? I don't belive it is, but can I use a for each loop for each piece of data in the collection? Or is there another way to iterate through the collect accessing all of the value.

Comment: Collection implements the `Iterator` interface, doesn't it? Couldn't you use that to **Iterate** through?

Comment: An `ArrayList` is a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). You should google "java collections"; google helps in situations like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Best way to iterate through an Collection (here ArrayList)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228687/java-best-way-to-iterate-through-an-collection-here-arraylist)

Comment: @Steve `interface Collection extends Iterable` but more less yes to what you say. ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `Collection` :

> The root interface in the collection hierarchy. A collection
>   represents a group of objects, known as its elements. Some collections
>   allow duplicate elements and others do not. Some are ordered and
>   others unordered.

You can iterate over it with `for` or `for-each` loop or using an `Iterator`.

The most common type of collections are :

- [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)
- [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)
- [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)
- [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Answer (score 5):

Iterating a `Collection<? extends E>` can be done with an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) (and you can get one with [`Collection.iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29) which can *iterate* the `Collection`) like

```
public static <E> void iterateWithIterator(Collection<? extends E> coll) {
    Iterator<? extends E> iter = coll.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        E item = iter.next();
        // do something with the item.
    }
}
```

or, with Java 5+, with a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
public static <E> void forEachIterate(Collection<? extends E> coll) {
    for (E item : coll) {
        // do something with the item.
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason in my case I get a compile error: error: incompatible types: Class<? extends E> cannot be converted to E. Any thoughts? Android/Java-7

Comment: PECS. Producer Extends, Consumer Super. Where you consume the collection, it should probably be `Collection<? super E> coll`